# loging with log4j stackoverflow error

Tags: android, eclipse, log4j

I am trying to add log statements in my code.

Using LogConfigurator, I wrote the following code in my MainActivity -

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class);




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
     logConfigurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
             + File.separator + "MyApp" + File.separator + "logs"
             + File.separator + "log4j.txt");
     logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
     logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
     logConfigurator.setFilePattern("%d %-5p [%c{2}]-[%L] %m%n");
     logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024 * 5 * 1024 );
     logConfigurator.setImmediateFlush(true);
     logConfigurator.configure();
     log.info("Execution of method onCreate started");


    MyTask mTask = new MyTask(); 
    mTask.execute();
     log.info("Execution of method onCreate ended");



}
```

It worked properly. But when I add

```
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JsonConversion.class);
```

in another class named JsonConversion and some more classes, I get the following error in my logcat

```
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963): java.lang.StackOverflowError
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at    org.apache.log4j.CategoryKey.equals(CategoryKey.java:47)
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:271)
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.getLogger(Hierarchy.java:273)
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.getLogger(Hierarchy.java:247)
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.example.news_android_mobile_application_cd.JsonConversion.<init>(JsonConversion.java:25)
    07-11 04:32:27.693: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.example.news_android_mobile_application_cd.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:25)
```

I have added log4j-1.2.17.jar and android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar . 
Can anybody help me out ?

Comment: Can you really have a 5GB file on an Android phone? Also, `1024 * 1024 * 5 * 1024` isn't what you think anyway, as the calculation exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @EricJablow yeah ! that is my mistake. I made the size 5 KB (5*1024) now, but still the error remains the same !

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know the exact answer but the following might be one of the reasons -

1. There were static methods in my program, so to use log in those method I made them non static and created different objects in different classes, which led to stackoverflow.
2. I made the log variable static and that did my work !

One more thing, the size of file should be kept in mind. If the size of data to be written exceeds the file size, then multiple files will be created.